# Why provide @+id/ each time in Android Relative layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Following is a code I picked from [this](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-relativelayout-example/) site. This pattern is used in a lot of similar codes.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button 1"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button 2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnButton1"/> <!-- Why use @+id again and not just @id/btnButton1  -->
```

AFAIK the + sign is a short cut to add the id to your list of resource ids. @+id/foo means you are creating an id named foo in the namespace of your application. You can refer to it using @id/foo.

So why not use `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnButton1` instead of `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnButton1` as the resource is already defined with the id?

Comment: AFAIK, one meaning of `+` is **create if not exists**.

Comment: In the R.java it provide the unique identification number for every item in android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's certainly a common pattern to use `@+id` identifier declaration syntax when referring to already declared identifiers.

Pros:

- You can re-order elements in your XML freely without needing to change the order of identifier declaration and reference.

Cons:

- Typos in identifier names are not automatically detected when attempting to refer to existing identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

well for once you need an anchor to use `layout_toRightOf`, that is why yo need to provide an id. Second you can omit the `+`. `+` stays for add to `R.id` class, but since it contains only static final field, its values is assigned once.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnButton1"/>` when referencing another view, no need to use the + sign

Answer (score 1):

You need to use code like this to define the view, you just provide id with '+' sign:

```
android:id="@+id/btnButton1"
```

After you defined it, it will appear in R.id class. Then you can use just a simple @id when you call it:

```
android:id="@id/btnButton1"
```

So when you reference to this view, you don't need '+' anymore:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button 2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnButton1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to add `@+id/` for the first occurrence of your ID and whenever you want to refer to it later use `@id/`

**BUT**

If you later changed the arrange of the XML file components and forgot to add the `+` sign at the first occurrence for your ID, the **application will crash** because you are trying to refer to an ID that has not been declared in your `R.java` file yet.

That's why it's ***recommended*** to use `@+id/` always to avoid such a problem like this.

I hope this helps you understand how it works